# "`$@': not a valid identifier" error in bash script

Tags: bash, shell

I am working on a shell script that will allow for the user to input a file name(s) into the command prompt, and the script will locate the executable file and determine if they could have been executed. However, when I attempt to run it, I get a "line 45 `$@': not a valid identifier" error message.

This is my first script and can't figure out how to address this error. I am hopeful that the rest of the script is ok, but I haven't been able to get past this one error to test it out.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
#!/bin/bash

FINDALL=FALSE

while :

    do
        case $1 in
            -a) FINDALL=TRUE
                shift ;;
            -h) echo “Usage $0 [-a] commands…”
                exit 0 ;;
            *)  break ;;
        esac
    done


for $@ in $file

    do
        case $file in
            */*)    if [ -x “$file” ]
                    then
                    echo $file

                    elif [ -d “$file” ]
                        then
                        echo $file is NOT found
                    fi
                    shift ;;

            *)  FOUND=FALSE ;;
        esac
    done


case $PATH in
    :*) PATH=”.:$PATH” ;;

    *::*)   PATH=`echo $PATH | sed -e ‘s/::/:.:/g’` ;;

    *:) PATH=”$PATH:.” ;;
esac


command=”$1”

IFS=$OLDIFS
IFS=:
set -- $PATH
IFS=$OLDIFS

case $command in
    */*)    echo $command ;;
    *)  FOUND=FALSE

        for P
            do
                if [ ! -d “$P/$command” -a -x “$P/$command” ]
                    then
                    FOUND=TRUE
                    echo $command
                    break
                    fi  
            done

        if [ “$FOUND” = FALSE ]
            then
            echo “Command $command not found in your search path”
        fi ;;
esac
```

Comment: Don't you mean `for file in $@`? Otherwise that loop doesn't make any sense.

Comment: And `for P` doesn't make much sense either. What's that supposed to do?

Comment: For your first comment, switching those two did allow for the script to run, so thank you! As for the second comment, that portion of the script was provided by my professor. Everything from "case $PATH in" and below. From the notes, I believe the P represents the PATH. I am not sure if that is correct or not, but our notes said to implement that code for the assignment.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude : `for P` is a shortcut for `for P in "$@"`.

Comment: The script as posted has a lot of fancy unicode quotes (like `“` and `‘`) rather than plain ASCII quotes (like `"` and `'`). If they're that way in the actual script, they will not work correctly, because the shell will not recognize the fancy quotes as shell syntax, just treat them as random characters. Some text editors "helpfully" translate your quotes into fancy versions -- for editing shell scripts, either figure out how to turn this feature off, or pick a text editor that doesn't do this.

Comment: Thank you for the tip on the unicode quotes! That is definitely helpful because I can see myself falling into that trap at some point. For this assignment, however, I typed my initial program directly into PuTTY and then retyped it into a Google Doc so I could look at it on my lunch break at work. I copy and pasted from the Google Doc into here, so that is probably why those types of quotes appeared.